# Go to very beginning of UINavigationController after going some pages deep

Tags: iphone, button, uinavigationcontroller, back

I want to go to the very beginning of the `UINavigationController` after going deep several pages.  If I try the following code, it will only go back one view.

`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

I want to do this action on a "cancel" button placed on the top right.

Comment: how do i do that?  you mean answer other questions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```